# i am gitting following error while rendring template in jsreport studio

Tags: jsreport

jsreport issue. I am getting this error on my local machine during design template. I don't understand what the issue. Please let me know what the problem.

```
{{/for}}
-----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', got 'OPEN_ENDBLOCK' Error: Parse error on line 206:
                        {{/for}}
-----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', got 'OPEN_ENDBLOCK'
     at Object.parseError (/home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:267:19)
     at Object.parse (/home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:336:30)
     at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse (/home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/base.js:46:43)
     at compileInput (/home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:514:19)
     at ret (/home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:523:18)
     at /home/amar/pureSpectrumJsReport/node_modules/jsreport-handlebars/lib/handlebarsEngine.js:26:14
     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:41
     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29)
     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:41:15)
     at Object.exports.runInNewContext (vm.js:72:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be using [jsrender](https://jsreport.net/learn/jsrender) syntax on [handlebars](https://jsreport.net/learn/handlebars) engine.

Switch the engine or use `#each`